# Finding out if shares are made available offline in Windows 7 by default without corrupting the offline files cache?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-7, group-policy, network-share

We have some rather large shares that people connect to at work, and it would be best if these shares did not even attempt to synchronize into the local Windows 7 offline files folder.

How does one check that this feature is not turned on, without the files beginning to synchronize?  And are the offline files settings controlled on the server, or on the local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a client-side setting, but as with most things, there's [a group of GPOs you can configure to control client offline files as well](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633429%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

To simply check its status on a client, probably the easiest way is to open up the `Sync Center` in the Control Panel and go to the  'Manage offline files` link (which you can also get to by typing "offline files") into the search bar in the start menu.

As to turning it of for specific folders, that's a Windows 8/Server 2012 GPO feature that I don't think is available for Windows 7.  I'm pretty sure that for Windows 7 you'll need to do some [scripting magic with the `net share /cache` switch in a logon script or the like](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755136.aspx).  It's very doable, just not as clean and easily manageable as as a GPO.  This is what I use in our domain to set which shares users cache into their offline files stores, though in your case, I guess you're looking for `/cache:none`.